# How to create conditional SQL insert using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I'm new to SQL and working in SQL Server. There is a table called `Employee` with columns `name, ssn, salary` etc. I am trying to write a trigger that checks salary is higher than $20000 when inserting rows.

If it's higher, then do insert, else print 'Salary must be higher'. I have done some research but couldn't find solution.

Here is what I'm thinking, but this it is not working for sure.

```
create trigger lowSalary 
on EMPLOYEE
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
        INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE

        IF salary < 20000 THEN
            print 'salary must be > 20000'
END
```

Additionally, I don't really understand this `instead of insert`. I found someone used this

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this through printing messages out of a trigger rather than adding a check constraint?

Comment: teacher siad it must be trigger

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Martin Smith's comment:

Have a look at this page on Check Constraints:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

In your case, you could create a constraint like:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_Salary CHECK (salary > 20000)
```

Comment: well the thing is it must be trigger.